# Watin used in webbrowser control, capturewebpagetofile() can't capture page

Tags: c#, browser, screenshot, watin

I want to create a screenshot of web page in WebBrowser Control, so I used Watin to achieve this. But capturewebpagetofile() capture all is black image. The web page is already loaded completed in WebBrowser. capturewebpagetofile() is worked fine except in WebBrowser. Why capturewebpagetofile() can't work in WebBrowser Control?

My code blow:

```
IE ie = new IE(webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance);
ie.GoTo(url);
ie.CaptureWebPageToFile(@"c:\test.png");
```

Comment: This post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536065/save-webbrowser-control-sceenshot-while-not-in-full-screen/9536258#9536258

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend using the ActiveXInstance, why not use WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser(); instead

Comment: What do you mean you don't "recommend" ?